# Set global where clause when I retrive data using laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a table `content`. So when I retrive anything from that table using laravel eloquent, I need to set a global where clause `Content::where('is_playlist', 1)->get();`, so that every time I retrieve data from that table, I should automatically filtered with that particular where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a scope function in the model to filter that out e.g:

```
public function scopePlaylist($query)
{
    return $query->where('is_playlist', 1);
}
```

This means you can easily call, `Content::playlist()->get()` and you'll have only playlist content.

I hope this is useful?